# how to import txt in sql with format file

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, format

I was using Access and i want change it to SQL. Now im trying to import the txt files that have a rarely format. In access i was importing with max length of character using "Specs", like this:

```
  Field Name       Data Type      Start   Width   Skip
     DNI           Long Integer     1       8       0
     CUIT           ouble           9       11      0
```

For example, the text file is like this

```
1810322027181032206Visa  201404300000005820.49           NA0000000822.550000
```

so i want "DNI" 8 character so in Access will import "18103220", "CUIT" start in the 11 Character and the legnth is 11, so will be "27181032206"...

Do you know something like this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server so have a look at [Using format file to bulk import data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But i havent got Field Terminator. My "Field Terminator" is the length of the field

Comment: Well the bcp format file allows you to specify fixed width files, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337558%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, i read it, but i dont understand where i have to create de Format File, is a file that i have to save in th computer or is a code that i have to script in SQL ?

Comment: The format file is outside the script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx